# AHCI and Memtest86+

Tags: windows, memory, raid, ahci

I've got a motherboard with SATA AHCI enabled, and I need to disable it to run Memtest86+ (because Window's [built-in RAM diagnostic tool](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=786) isn't worth a barrel of warm snot), and because the Memtest developers are too lazy to fix the bootloader problem. Fine, I know how to do that.

The problem is, I, in a moment of insanity driven by the fact that I work with hardware RAID cards all the time, felt the need to enable the onboard RAID. In retrospect, this was stupid: the onboard raid is a joke, but I'm stuck with it.

My question is, *if* I disable AHCI am I going to lose the RAID information? I haven't been able to find a definitive yes or no anywhere, and I'm not in the mood to find out the hard way.

**EDIT**: The motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-EP45-UD3P](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128358)

**EDIT2**: People need to stop telling me to boot off a live CD. My optical drives are both SATA, and with AHCI enabled, Memtest86 stalls permanently at the "Loading......................" stage. This is the whole problem.

The USB key thing is a good idea, but the Floppy thing? Does anyone still have a floppy drive? I have an old external, but I can't be bothered to buy disks.

**EDIT3**: So, usb key. Worked for about 4 hours trying to make a Vista-bootable USB key (never done it, or needed to do it before, but thought I'd *better* myself), which was a micro-epic that culminated in me, drunk and frustrated, with a usb key that had been formatted, diskpart'd, and bootsect'd about 20 times, to no avail. Threw it out the window.

Took a fresh key, made it linux bootable (had to download the tools, so it took 5 minutes), installed the linux version, and it booted like a charm. Goddamn it.

Memtest86+ didn't work as well as I'd hoped: I couldn't localize the bad module exactly, and I ended up having to do the "RAM-shuffle" after all, but it did throw errors much faster than the crappy Windows version.

I'm planning on de-RAIDing the system this weekend, so when I get my new image made, I'll disable AHCI and see if it kills the RAID, just for the sake of experiment.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Turns out there was bad RAM *AND* bad slots. Not sure what the hell happened there, but it explains why I was never able to localize the problem. Installed new RAM and new Mobo, and hasn't had a problem since.

Comment: ... why didn't you run memtest from a livecd??

Comment: btw, this sounds like any real answer will be specific to the RAID chipset on the motherboard, so might as well tell us now what it is.

Comment: @quack quixote: You can't. It won't boot from CD while AHCI mode is enabled. That's the whole point.

Comment: Tried the USB option (or any other option) yet?

Comment: @satanicpuppy: ah.  sorry, that you were using SATA optical drives was not clear to me; with the stuff about RAID in there, i thought you were trying to boot memtest off a SATA HDD.  this really should've been two separate questions to avoid confusing the AHCI-RAID and AHCI-Memtest issues.

Comment: 'For the sake experiment' - ah, that's the spirit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [bootable USB disk](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm), and then run the [Memtest86+ pre-compiled EXE for USB disks](http://www.memtest.org/download/4.00/memtest86+-4.00.exe.zip).

Answer (score 0):

You can run Memtest86+ form a bootable [CD](http://www.memtest.org/download/4.00/memtest86+-4.00.iso.zip), [Floppy](http://www.memtest.org/download/4.00/memtest86+-4.00.floppy.zip) or [USB](http://www.memtest.org/download/4.00/memtest86+-4.00.exe.zip) key.  None of which should require disabling AHCI to boot from.

If you have to disable AHCI to boot from these devices you've got bigger problems than possibly bad RAM (probably a defective motherboard).

You should be able to disable AHCI or RAID and then re-enable without losing settings/data. If you're extra paranoid, perhaps unplug the drives before disabling it.

Comment: The default memtest86+ wont boot from AHCI-controlled SATA optical drives - nothing wrong with the OPs PC at all - it's purely a (well known) memtest problem...

Comment: Unplugging the disk drive and changing mobo to IDE should work - but seems a little too much work compared to USB solution IMHO.

Comment: Weird, I guess we've never gone back to booting Memtest from a CD since before we swtiched to SATA optical drives, we just got in the habit of using a bootable USB drive long before that. :) Good to know.